# Put a function in an XML field

Tags: php, xml, database, data-binding, function

Is it possible to put a function in an XML field?

For example i have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<prova>
<prova>
<continente>Europa</continente> 
<stato>Italia</stato> 
<societa>SSC Napoli</societa> 
<actual>1.09769</actual> 
<estimate>0.447969</estimate> 
</prova>
<prova>
....
</prova>
</prova>
```

Is it possible to insert a function into 'actual' and 'estimate' fields which change randomly by a timer the values?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Franky, can you please tell how that XML file is generated?

Comment: I've built a InnoDB database with mySQL and then i get the XML code
the xml has to populate a flex datagrid by httpservice asynchronous request, so i want to simulate values changing by a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try something like this:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('provas.xml');

$provas = $doc->getElementsByTagName("prova");
foreach( $provas as $prova )
{
    $actual = $prova->getElementsByTagName("actual");
    $estimate = $prova->getElementsByTagName("estimate");

    $random = $doc->createElement("random", "your data");
    $actual->appendChild( $random );
    $estimate->appendChild( $random );
}
?>
```

Comment: the php is automatically generated by Flex Builder and it's composed by 397 code lines so i really don't know how it's possible to manage it. Howhewer thanks

Comment: @Franky, you'll need to take XML returned by your webservice and to edit it; this keywords can help to search: `"xml, php, dom, xpath, appendchild"`

Answer (score 1):

You would want any function to be part of what generated the xml, not the xml itself. In otherwords, you would have some script update and actually generate the xml with updated values.

Answer (score 1):

However you generate the XML is the place to put this function. If you generate the XML via PHP you would do a `<?php echo blah ?>` in the middle. However, if it's static XML that you hand built, then no, there is no way to put a function in.

Comment: yeah it's generated by a php request from a client by httpservice e4x format

Answer (score 0):

No.

XML is a simple data format which does support functions.
Unlike HTML, you can't put in a Javascript block inside an XML file to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Chuck above.
Either generate the XML with the desired values, in which case the "function" would be part of the generation, or use XSL to transform to HTML, but you cannot ultimately embed "content that changes" inside the XML, you can only "give" the XML the value after generation.